# Do I have to install AWS CLI in each server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have multiple standalone servers from where I want to `upload/sync` directories to Object Storage usign `AWS CLI`. 
Do I have to install AWS CLI in each server? OR is there a common console/platform provided within AWS Object Storage from where I can call the same command over something like say SSH. How can I avoid installing cli to all the servers?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid installing the awscli to these servers? Note that it's pre-installed on all Amazon Linux and Linux 2 servers by default.

Comment: Are your "multiple servers" on your own hardware, or on Amazon EC2?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein own standalone hardwares

Answer (score 1):

You have to install AWS CLI in all the servers even if you write the script to ssh from a single server that which is installed AWS CLI, SSH protocol will take the configuration from the remote server, not from a server where the script is running. It's better if you use a configuration management tool like ansible to speed up the process.